# Making authorization of roles work after installing Ninject?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, roles, authorize

I'm currently working on my exam project in ASP.NET MVC 5 (C#).

My problem is one of my controllers, which is heavily relying on the authorize roles attribute to make sure people have a certain role and thereby access to the various functions in the controller. It was working fine, right until I wanted to use dependency injection through the constructor... it seems after I installed ninject for mvc3, set up the bind and made the constructor accepting the interface in the controller. That it just ignores all authorize tags? I know it's not syntax errors because nothing is different in the controller, except the new constructor. This seems to have no effect on the account controller though so I have to presume Ninject is messing things up.

Everyone can do everything they want and run all methods in the controller since I set it up for ninject and I simply don't get it?

Can anyone help or know of this issue and any steps to take to fix it?

I have to turn in the project monday so I was hoping some guru could enlighten me relatively fast on this issue. A google search tells me Ninject doesn't work with the attribute is that true? If it is I'm pretty screwed.

Well I basically added this to the NinjectWebCommon's "RegisterServices" method:

```
kernel.Bind<IChildRepository>().To<ChildRepository>();
```

(I'm making a site for an institution that watches kids after school etc. the childcontroller controls the management of "children" created in the system).

```
private readonly IChildRepository _childRepository;

public ChildController(IChildRepository childRepository)
{
    _childRepository = childRepository;
}
```

This is my repository class:

```
public class ChildRepository : IChildRepository
    {
        ChildContext context = new ChildContext();


    public IQueryable<Child> All
    {
        get { return context.Children; }
    }

    public IQueryable<Child> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<Child, object>>[]     includeProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<Child> query = context.Children;
        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }
        return query;
    }

    public Child Find(int id)
    {
        return context.Children.Find(id);
    }

    public void InsertOrUpdate(Child child)
    {
        if (child.ChildId == default(int))
        {
            context.Children.Add(child);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Entry(child).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        var child = context.Children.Find(id);
        context.Children.Remove(child);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        context.Dispose();
    }

}
```

And my repo interface:

```
public interface IChildRepository : IDisposable
    {
        IQueryable<Child> All { get; }
        IQueryable<Child> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<Child, object>>[] includeProperties);
        Child Find(int id);
        void InsertOrUpdate(Child child);
        void Delete(int id);
        void Save();
    }
```

This is the index method in the controller method to show you how I'm using authorize:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, CanEdit")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_childRepository.All.ToList());
    }
```

How it works now? You can access the childcontroller views and all the other methods besides index without even being logged into the system?

Comment: I tried to create a new MVC 5 project and added `Ninject.MVC3` package and `[Authorize]` attribute worked just fine being applied to controller class or a particular action. Could you please provide some code that you use to register dependencies?

Comment: Updated with some code

Comment: Do you have any other dependencies registered in the `RegisterServices` method? Could you try to create `ChildRepository` in the controller constructor and remove interface as a parameter? Just to see if it changes something.

Comment: No I am not doing anything else in the registerservices method besides that and as soon as I remove the interface as a parameter and init the repo in the constructor, everything works perfectly. The login screen pops up when I try to manually access the childcontroller methods. So it is ninject causing this somehow :/

Comment: No suggestions? Doing searches on it isn't really leading me to any type for solution :/ I guess I might have to exclude unit testing completely if I can't get this to work, which will look bad on my exam. I role authorizations are fundamental for my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem by googling, apparently adding this line to the registerservices method solves the entire issue.

```
kernel.Bind<IFilterProvider>().To<FilterAttributeFilterProvider>();
```

Got it from this guy which I love right now:
http://pieterderycke.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/using-asp-net-filters-with-the-ninject-depencency-resolver/

Thought I would answer the question myself so if others run into the same issue they can make it work!

Comment: This is pretty strange, because `IFilterProvider` is bound in the `MvcModule` class from `Ninject.Web.Mvc` and this module is automatically loaded by Ninject kernel. Anyway, I'm glad you've fixed your issue.

Comment: I can't explain why it works better than that article already does, but it does solve the issue and in the end what more can you ask.